# Send keyboard command to server over HTTP

Tags: http, networking, keyboard

I want to be able to send a keyboard command from a browser to a Mac running XAMPP on the same network.

I've used arduino before setup with an ethernet shield that acted as a USB keyboard but I'm looking for a software solution this time around.

Does anyone know which direction to point me in?